# Use Dijkstras to find the "k" shortest path

Tags: c#, algorithm, dijkstra, path-finding

It is already possible for me to find the shortest route between two vertex points, using Dijkstra's algorithm: [wiki Dijkstra's](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm).

BUT. Some of my edges are meant to be used as "checkpoints", as in you have to go through at least one checkpoint in order for a route to be available.

Sometimes, the algorithm will find a path that contains none of these edge-checkpoints. In that case I want to find the 2nd. shortest route - and if that route doesn't contain a checkpoint either, then find the 3rd. shortest route, and so on.

Any ideas how to get me started?

EDIT:

Would it be possible to go through all the predecessors on the first route, and then run Dijkstras from the predecessor to the destination (and exclude the original choice of the predecessor's next goto vertex). In that way I could possibly find all possible routes, and then compare them to each other?

Example.

A = source
Z = destination

shortest path:      A -> B -> C -> D -> Z

2nd. shortest path: A -> B -> C -> D -> "Vertex with lowest cost, which is NOT Z" (loop this through all D's unvisited neighbors if it doesn't find an available path in current try)

if 2nd. shortest path doesn't contain checkpoint either, try 3rd shortest

3rd. shortest path: A -> B -> C -> Vertex with lowest cost, which is NOT D

Or is this solution not possible in any way?

EDIT 2:

[image: Picture]
It may be very hard to see, but the purple 1x3 pixels are the vertices. The yellow roads are edges, and so are the pink 3x3 pixels. The pink ones are also the so called checkpoints. So I have to find the shortest route and go through at least one checkpoint.

Comment: do you have any other information about the topography of the graph? is it an oriented graph? if yes, can it contain loops?

Comment: Please make clear in the question that you *must* use Dijkstra's algorithm.

Comment: Also, how does one get to Greenalnd?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few ways you could attempt to make this work.

Let's call S the starting node, D the destination node, and I the intermediate node.

[Single Intermediate node]
A simple but sub-optimal solution would be to use Dijkstra from S to I and then append the result of Dijkstra from I to D.

[Multiple Intermediate nodes]
As Niklas B. pointed out a feasible approach would be "*Build the shortest path trees from S and D. For each intermediate node A, check d(S, A) + d(T, A). The minimum is the solution. Runtime is twice that of Dijkstra, e.g. O((n+m) log n) with binary heaps*".

Comment: Good solution, but it wouldn't really work if there are multiple "checkpoints". From the pluralization in the question, I think there are in this case.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by the "intermediate node"? Is it a single node that is to be set, or should I set one every time I search for the nearest neighbor node?

Comment: There are like 10 available checkpoints, but it only has to go through one of them.

Comment: Okay thanks for the edit, but I can't just choose an intermediate node, since there are several checkpoints available, and it has to be the closest.

Comment: Unless of course I try to build a path for every single instance of checkpoints. If 10 checkpoints, build 10 paths with a checkpoint as I. And then compare them in the end. Think I might try this, even though it's probably not the most effective one in terms of performance.

Comment: The problem is that you're restricted by the use of Dijkstra, since there would be more efficient approaches using as example Floyd-Marshall's algorithm.

Comment: Dijkstra is good. Build the shortest path trees from S and D. For each intermediate node A, check d(S, A) + d(D,A). The minimum is the solution. Runtime is twice that of Dijkstra, e.g. O((n+m) log n) with binary heaps

Comment: Oh and if the checkpoints are fixed and you get multiple (S, D) queries, do it the other way round: precompute the shortest path trees from each checkpoint. Then you can answer a query in O(number of checkpoints)

Comment: Thank you guys, I worked my way around it. Got a bit complicated and messy, but I'll use this for now :)

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion is - add more dimensions to store what chekpoints was passed.

So, states `(x1,x2)` would be replaced by: `(x1,x2,c1...c_n)` where `c1..cn` are boolean flags for each checkpoint.

And edges `(x1,x2)->(y1,y2)` would be replaced as:

- `(x1,x2, c1..cn)->(y1,y2, c1..cn)` for non checkpoint states
- `(x1,x2, c1..cn)->(y1,y2, c1..c(x-1), true ,c(x+1)..cn)` for checkpoint state `cx`

for any `c1..cn`

Search algorithm itself would be the same, but number of states would be multiplied by `2^n`

**edit:**
Also, if required to match at least one (not few different) checkpoints, vector `c1..cn` can be replaced by one flag which would describe is at least one checkpoint passed.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I must admit I really don't understand much of what you are explaining here. I am not that hardcore, just a student.

Comment: @SimonSondrupKristensen, there is not as many hardcore, as it can seem on first look... you are just changing you graph a bit, by adding extra information about passed checkpoints.. in other words is just  like adding layers on a map for each passed checkpoints combination

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how frequently your graph is changing, you might try the Floyd Warshall algorithm.  It will help you construct a matrix that will show you the shortest path between any pair of nodes.  Once you have that, you can iterate over your checkpoints using Saverio Terracciano's answer to figure out which checkpoint is the best one to go through.

Answer (score 0):

For each node, instead of having the lowest cost, you have n lowest costs, where n is the number of checkpoints needed to visit. Assuming as you said you need N/M and the order and which N does not matter.

Then as you propagate cost, you track checkpoints and update the corresponding n slot for the information needed. You would likely want to limit n to the minimum because if you need 2 checkpoints and pass 3 you still have 2, but the extra is of no value.

Answer (score 0):

You can also convert this to a TSP problem to get the best route:

- Use normal weights for Start node S and intermediate nodes I
- Use infinite weight from S to end node E (we want to simply remove / ignore the roundtrip connecting start and end point)
- Use 0 weight to connect end point E and start point S

Now for each checkpoint:

- add check point as intermediate pount to the base trip
- calculate tour length using TSP, and distance between nodes using Dijkstra and remember this length that passes this checkpoint

The shortest of those tours is the optimal tour, and passes only one check point.